# How to compare randomly generated OTP/Number in PHP with the user input

Tags: php, html, compare, one-time-password

I have viewed other similar threads but could not find what I was looking for.

So here I am generating a random number for Otp and sending it to the end user. Now my problem is how do I compare the value input by the user and the randmoly generated number in PHP.

I am not using any database for this purpose so I require a database free solution.

Here is my HTML form.

```
<html>
<head>
<h1> Working Otp sample</h1>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="sendotp.php">
<input type="tel" name="phone"> <br>
<button type="submit" name="sub">Submit</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="sendotp.php">
<input type="tel" name="otp"> <br>
<button type="submit" name="sub2">Submit</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code which sends and verifies the OTP.

I think the if part in "else if" is not executed & also calling $myotp there(in else if) generates a new number every time.
I can't seem to find a solution for it, please Help.

Thanks in advance for your time and input on this!

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;


if(isset ($_POST['sub']))
{
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

function generate()
{
    $digits_needed=6;

    $random_number=''; // set up a blank string

    $count=0;

    while ( $count < $digits_needed ) {
        $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);
        
        $random_number .= $random_digit;
        $count++;
    }
    
    return $random_number;
}

$myotp = generate();

    
$account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$twilio_number = "+1234567890";

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->messages->create(
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    $phone,
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => "Your OTP is $myotp"
    )
);
}
else if(isset ($_POST['sub2']))
{
    
    $otp = $_POST['otp'];
    echo "OTP is $otp";
    if($otp == $myotp)
    {
        echo "OTP successfully verified!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please enter valid OTP";
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create it, you can store it in a session variable. Then just compare what you get from the user with that value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can u please drop a snippet for it or some reference. I am new to php and don't know how to use it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look in [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) about sessions. They will most likely explain it better than I can.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay! Thanks.